# Unable to add tags when launching EC2 instance via AWS SDK for PHP (no CLI)

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-web-services, instances

I am able to successfully launch new instances using AWS SDK for PHP. However, I am not able to add tags ('Name' = 'New Instance'). I tried doing it in several ways, with the following seeming the most reasonable. However, upon refreshing the EC2 dashboard, I can see that the new instance is created, however, the name tag is still blank.

```
        $ec2Client = new Ec2Client([
            'region' => 'xx-xxxx-1',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'profile' => 'default'
        ]);
        // Launch an instance with the key pair and security group
        $result = $ec2Client->runInstances(array(
            'ImageId'           => 'ami-xxxxxxxx',
            'MinCount'          => 1,
            'MaxCount'          => 1,
            'InstanceType'      => 't2.large',
            'KeyName'           => 'xxxxxx',
            'SubnetId'          => 'subnet-xxxxxxxx',
            'VpcId'             => 'vpc-xxxxxxxx',
            'Tags'              => array(
                                        'Key' => 'Name',
                                        'Value' => 'New Instance',
                                    ),
            'SecurityGroups'[1] => 'sg-xxxxxxxx',
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of SDK you are using, but from [AWS v2 SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_runInstances) documentation there is no `Tags` key.

Try using other function [`createTags`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_createTags). Note that `Tags` is double array, not like in your example.

```
$ec2Client->createTags([
    'Resources' => [$result['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']],
    'Tags' => [
        ['Key' => '', 'Value' => ''],
        ['Key' => '', 'Value' => ''],
    ]
]);
```

Comment: I am using the latest version 3. Anyway, I did miss out what the documentation was saying and I had found the solution to this. I will update this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Justinas for pointing out using version 2. I am however using the version 3 SDK and had found the answer in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#runinstances.

Tested and working, the Tag can be done under TagSpecifications under the RunInstances operation as follow:

```
'TagSpecifications' => [
    [
        'ResourceType' => 'instance',
        'Tags' => [
            [
                'Key' => 'Name',
                'Value' => 'New Instance Name',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

More information about TagSpecifications array structure can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#shape-tagspecification, and for Tag structure over here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#shape-tag